# boost::containers and error: "C2679: binary '=': no operator found"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, boost

I'm trying to compile the following pice of code under Visual Studio 2008:

```
struct test
{
    boost::container::vector<int> v1;
};
test v1, v3;
const test & v2 = v3;
v1 = v2;
```

The error I'm getting is:
*error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const test' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

could be 'test &test::operator =(test &)' 
while trying to match the argument list '(test, const test)'*

When normal std::vector is used instead of boost::container equivalent, code compiles. I'm looking for an answer why this code doesn't compile and how to make it compile.

Comment: FWIW, the following code compiles under MSVC10: #include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
struct test
{
    boost::container::vector<int> v1;
};
int main()
{
 test v1, v3;
 const test & v2 = v3;
 v1 = v2;
}

Comment: Another FWIW: GCC 4.7.2 using `-std=gnu++03` fails in a manner similar to VC++ 2008.  It compiles fine using `-std=gnu++11`, but then again, the whole point of the boost move library (which is what `boost::container::vector` is using that's causing the problem) is to provide move semantics to C++03 implementations, so it's not too surprising that there's no problem when compiled using a compiler/compiler mode that supports C++11 move semantics. It looks like there might be a bug in boost move dealing with copyable const objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a similar question that already has been asked:
[boost::container::vector fails to compile with C++03 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083360/boostcontainervector-fails-to-compile-with-c03-compiler)

It seems that the behaviour we are observing is designed and known to the boost community:
[Boost::move emulation limitations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/move/emulation_limitations.html#move.emulation_limitations.assignment_operator) chapter "*Assignment operator in classes derived from or holding copyable and movable types*".

In order to make the code shown in the main question to work one must declare class as copyable and movable using BOOST_COPYABLE_AND_MOVABLE macro. Also const version of the copy assignment needs to be defined explicitly. Corrected version of the code for C++03 compiler:

```
class test
{
private:
    BOOST_COPYABLE_AND_MOVABLE( test );
public:
    test& operator=(BOOST_COPY_ASSIGN_REF(test) p) // Copy assignment
    {
        v1 = p.v1;
        return *this;
    }
    boost::container::vector<int> v1;
};
```

Those additional class decorations may indeed become annoying especially when the codebase is large. Crawling through the code and adding assign operators is not a thing I would like to spend my time on.

Comment: I wish questions/answers like this one got more attention/upvotes.  Much more interesting than the usual.

Comment: On  a side note, this seems only required when the class has complex types such as vectors for some reason. Simple (Inlcuding custom) types don't report this error.